# How to name an labe an array already entered

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two buttons a textbox and a list box. I entered 25 numbers into a textbox that displays into a listbox. Some how I have to creat an array name from that listbox and display them in another list box in assending order. This is the last step that I can figure out. Any suggestion would be helpful

---

Code from Comments

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click 
    If ListBox5Box.Items.Count < 20 Then 'this works 
        MessageBox.Show("Exactly Twenty Numbers Must Be Entered") 
        ListBox6.Items.Add(GoLstBox5.Text)'this does not work nothing comes over to listbox6 
        Dim beerArray(19) As Integer beerArray(19) = GoLstBox.Text Array.Sort(beerArray)'this will work once the other works 
        For i = 0 To beerArray.GetUpperBound(0) 
            ListBox6.Items.Add(beerArray(i).ToString)
        Next
```

I now have this but nothing displays into the new listbox

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    If ListBox1.Items.Count < 20 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Exactly Twenty Numbers Must Be Entered")

        ' ListBox6.Items.Add(GoLstBox.Text)


        Dim beerArray(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Object
        Listbox1.Items.CopyTo(beerArray, 0)

        Array.Sort(beerArray)
        For i = 0 To beerArray.GetUpperBound(0)
            ListBox6.Items.AddRange(beerArray)
        Next            
    End If
End Sub
...
```

Comment: Can you clarify - so u need to display same number in another listbox, but sorted? What do u need array for? Also, is this ASP.NET or WinForm application?

Comment: Post the code you've written so far.

Comment: if I put them into an array and have an array name I can do many more things with it.  know how to sort if it were and array. eventually I want to eliminate the duplicates that a user may enter. I only know how to do this if it is already an array. righ now I am just trying to figure out how to get the whole list to display into the next listbox (listBox) as an array named beerArray.

Comment: Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        If ListBox5Box.Items.Count < 20 Then 'this works
            MessageBox.Show("Exactly Twenty Numbers Must Be Entered")

        ListBox6.Items.Add(GoLstBox5.Text)'this does not work nothing comes over to listbox6


            Dim beerArray(19) As Integer
            beerArray(19) = GoLstBox.Text

            Array.Sort(beerArray)'this will work once the other works
            For i = 0 To beerArray.GetUpperBound(0)
                ListBox6.Items.Add(beerArray(i).ToString)

Comment: @JasonSmith please do not put code in the comments, it looks extremely messy, just edit your question and add it. I did for you this time :)

Comment: you do not need the last for statement, you are adding all of the items for each iteration. if you want to do that use `ListBox6.Items.Add(beerArray(i))`

Comment: Your If Statement is wrong also, see the edit I made to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ListBox.ObjectCollection.CopyTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.copyto.aspx) to retrieve your Listbox.Items into an Array.
You will notice that I changed your beerArray to an Object array from an Integer Array, this is because once the items are stored in the ListBox as Objects. So other than creating a Function to process the Items and return them this would be the way to go.

```
 Dim beerArray(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Object
 ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(beerArray, 0)

 'Manipulate your array here
 'Then add it to your Second ListBox
 ListBox2.Items.AddRange(beerArray)
```

---

Edit base on added code by OP

Your If statement is wrong, your second ListBox will not be populated if your first ListBox's item count is 20 or greater. You need to do something like this.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count <> 20 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Exactly Twenty Numbers Must Be Entered")

    Else

        Dim beerArray(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Object
        ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(beerArray, 0)

        Array.Sort(beerArray)

        For i = 0 To beerArray.GetUpperBound(0)
            ListBox6.Items.Add(beerArray(i))
        Next

        'If you want to use the AddRange you do not need the above For Loop Just use this
        'ListBox6.Items.AddRange(beerArray)        

    End If


End Sub
```